# Disabling vsync in Unity/Mutter/Compiz?

Tags: unity, compiz, mutter

Yesterday I was still using Natty with Compiz.  I had noticed that disabling Vsync in Compiz made dragging windows much more smooth and responsive (I don't mind the tearing).

I installed Ocelot this morning which seems to use Mutter by default (I may be wrong there, I'm still kind of lost).  Dragging windows has the same sluggish feeling as with Compiz and Vsync enabled.  So I was thinking I could try disabling Vsync.

Can vsync be disabled/enabled in Mutter?

Edit to answer the comments:

```
$ ps -ef | grep compiz | grep $USER
<myname>  3989  3908  5 12:14 ?        00:03:38 compiz
<myname>  4051  3989  0 12:15 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/compiz-decorator
<myname> 15409 15406  0 13:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep compiz
```

So indeed I was confused.  If I'm running Compiz I should manage to bend it to my will.

Comment: First, let's find out if you're running Unity 2D or 3D. Please run this in a terminal and add the output to your question. `ps -ef | grep compiz | grep $USER`

Comment: ummm - are you running gnome-shell or the unity interface?

Comment: Unity uses compiz not mutter.

Comment: @fossdreedom  I'm using the unity interface.

Comment: @Javier Rivera  Good to know.  I got confused.

Comment: @jrg Looks like I'm running Compiz!  I'll see if I can configure it.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all,

Since you proved me I was running Compiz, I downloaded *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and disabled Vsync under the OpenGL tab.  That did it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two implementations of Unity in Ubuntu. The primary one uses Compiz and the "fallback" uses Metacity. Gnome Shell uses Mutter, but the "fallback" for Gnome Shell, which is the classic Ubuntu desktop (Gnome Panel) uses Metacity... It's easy to get a little confused these days. :)